# Is there a way to ignore certain transitionend events based on css property?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to ignore certain transitionend events based on css property? For example in the following code, the height transition ends much sooner than the left transition. Is there a way to ignore the height transition to get the last transitionend event?

html:

```
<div id="testButton"></div>

<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <div id="menu-sets" class="menu-sets">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#testButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.menu-sets {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    background-color: #ff0000;

    transition: left 3.3s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.show-menu-1 .menu-sets {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testButton").click(
        function () {
            $('#wrapper').addClass('show-menu-1'); // show menu
        }
    );

    $('#menu-sets').one('transitionend', function() { 
        alert("event done");
    });
});
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rotaercz/zysxsc41/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is, the original event contains information about the property being transitioned

```
$('#menu-sets').on('transitionend', function(event) { 

    if ( event.originalEvent.propertyName === 'left' ) {
        alert('done');
        $('#menu-sets').off('transitionend');
    }

});
```

As `one()` only fires once, you'll have to use `on()` and unbind instead

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zysxsc41/3/)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore height so it doesn't fire a transitionend event? Basically I'd like to get the transitionend event from the left property which finishes slower.

Comment: Nope, if will fire the event, but you can filter it out in the event handler